# Asp.net core MVC Identity Add and get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Hey I have generated template with microsoft login. I want to add identity when you visit one page. My code:

```
            int OsCislo = //Gets params from model
            string name = //Gets params from model
            List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> MyClaim = new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>()
            {
                new System.Security.Claims.Claim (System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, name),
                new System.Security.Claims.Claim (System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role, OsCislo.ToString())
            };
            System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity identity = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity();
            identity.AddClaims(MyClaim);
            User.AddIdentity(identity);
            ///Find identity and read from it
```

What I am trying to do: 
 1. Get Data 
 2. Make List of Claims where I put my data 
 3. Make new identity and feed it Claims. 
 4. Add identity to 
existing user 
 5. Find That Identity throught User and get data from Claims.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! If somebody want code here it is:

```
            int CisloG = Model.Where(s => s.UserName.Contains(name)).ToArray().First().One;
            name = Model.Where(s => s.UserName.Contains(name)).ToArray().First().Two + " " + Model.Where(s => s.UserName.Contains(name)).ToArray().First().Three;
            List<Claim> MyClaim = new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>()
            {
                new Claim (ClaimTypes.GivenName, name),
                new Claim (ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, CisloG.ToString()),
                new Claim (ClaimTypes.Email, User.Identity.Name)
            };
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            identity.AddClaims(MyClaim);
            User.AddIdentity(identity);
            ///Getting data
            var Name = User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.GivenName).ToList().ElementAt(1).Value;
            var OsCislo = User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).ToList().ElementAt(1).Value;
            var Email = User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Email).ToList().ElementAt(0).Value;
            Console.WriteLine(Name + "(" + OsCislo + ") " + Email);
```

If sombody wants to know what it does just add commment.